# Using Services vs. MediaPlayer and SoundPool

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

So my friends and I are trying to make a game with sound effects and background music. One of us implemented the background music using Services but it's really unstable and causes the app to crash sometimes.

I was wondering what's the benefit of using a Service?

Also, I was wondering if we could just use a MediaPlayer to play the background music and a SoundPool to play the sound effects? ..or is that bad style or inefficient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works for me best (and I think is accepted in general) is to use the MediaPlayer for music and SoundPool for sound effects.

I believe you should try to avoid using a Service to play music or sounds (since the idea behind a service is that it should run in the background). Yet if you don't want to play any sound in the UI thread, you could create an additional thread. I personally call all my sounds from the main thread and it seems to work all fine.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering what's the benefit of using a Service?

Using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to control your sounds is useful when you want your app to keep running the sounds even if it is not in the foreground. One good example is a Music App. It would be reasonable to keep the music running when the user hit the Home button for example.

Now, regarding your second question, yes you should use [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for your game music and [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) for the effects. However, you should also consider putting them in a separate thread *if* you notices performance issues.